# Shortest path between list of list

Tags: python, loops, recursion

Let's say I have a list such as this:

```
[
[1, [2, 3]],
[2, [4, 5]],
[4, [6, 7]],
[3, [7]]
]
```

I want to write code that would find the shortest path from `1` to `7`, which, in this case, would be `1 -> 3 -> 7`.

This is what I have so far:

```
start = 1
lst = [[1, [2, 3]], [2, [4, 5]], [4, [6, 7]], [3, [7]]]

def getIt(start):
    for nest in lst:
        if start == lst[0]:
            return(nest[1])

allLists = []
loopCleaner = []
def travel(paths, totalList):
    if paths is not None:
        if 7 in paths:
            allLists.append(totalList)
        else:
            for path in paths:
                if path not in loopCleaner:
                    loopCleaner.append(path)
                    totalList.append(path)
                    travel(getIt(path), totalList)

print(travel(lst, []))
```

---

I'm trying this through a mix of recursion and loop, but it either outputs way too long of a path or just None.

**My logic**: get all the possible nested lists through `getIt`.

Then iterate through those through recursion and keep adding to total list as it goes down, until 7 is found in one of those paths. In which case, we end and exit. How do I code in such a way that I simply get `[1, 3, 7]`?

Comment: That list looks like an adjacency matrix. Did you look into Djikstras algorithm for shortest path?

Comment: the `NetworkX` module has a `shortest_path()` function implemented, as stated by @rdas, if you manage to turn that into an adjancency matrix or a Graph, you should be easily able to find the shortest path

Comment: I haven't tried that, how would I make it into an adjacency matrix or is it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def paths(d, start, end, c = [], seen=[]):
  if end in d.get(start, []):
     yield c+[end]
  else:
     for i in filter(lambda x:x not in seen, d.get(start, [])):
        yield from paths(d, i, end, c = c+[i], seen=seen+[i])

data = [[1, [2, 3]], [2, [4, 5]], [4, [6, 7]], [3, [7]]]
print(min(list(paths(dict(data), 1, 7, c=[1])), key=len))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 7]
```

Comment: When trying it out on my full data set I get `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` But for the minimum viable it works perfectly. There are definitely loops possible so I'll look into it.

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh If possible, could you post a larger sample of your dataset with some desired start and end values?

Comment: Tried your new function, it works! That's way easier than I thought. Can you explain how it works please?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh No problem. The code above converts the original list to a dictionary for cleaner and more efficient key lookup and then iterates over the child values stored in each sublist. If the `end` value is found in the child list, the running list of keys is yielded. At each `paths` call, the child values being iterated over are added to the `seen` list, to ensure that the function can ignore loops and prevent an infinite recursive error.